# Insufficient permission of TFS admin

Tags: tfs

Navigating to a project page of a TFS 2013 collection by Administrator account returns this error:
http://server:8080/tfs/DMS/ProjectX

```
Error
The page you are looking for is currently unavailable.

TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation: Administrator. The following permissions are needed to perform this operation: View project-level information.
```

The modification of TFS administration console is also disabled as is seen in this screenshot:
[image]

How can I grant full access to this team project collection?

Answer (score 1):

Administrator accounts do not automatically get TFS Administrator capability and it must be granted explicitly.

You need to speak to your TFS Admin and get them to grant access to your account.

If you are the TFS Admin you need the account that was used to install TFS.